# Count total files and folders of a drive powershell

Tags: windows, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, scripting-language, infrastructure

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and right click properties in C:\ shows the number and size of all the files and folders of the drive.
How should I do it in powershell?? I need the exact and count so that the output of the script shows the same result.

I tried `Get-ChildItem "C:\" -recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum`

Output is
Count : 102809
Average :
Sum : 25145552806
Property : length
But thats not the correct number
thanks in advance

Comment: did you try anything ?

Comment: I tried Get-ChildItem "C:\" -recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum
Output is 

Count    : 102809
Average  :
Sum      : 25145552806
Maximum  :
Minimum  :
Property : length
But thats not the correct number.

Comment: this is the error after that 

Get-ChildItem : Access to the path 'C:\Documents and Settings' is denied.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ChildItem "C:\" -recurse -Force | Measure-Object -property length -sum
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Documents and Settings:String) [Get-ChildItem], Unauthoriz
   Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `force` parameter of `get-childitem`.

[from the doc](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh849800(v=WPS.620).aspx) :

> -Force
>   Allows the cmdlet to get items that cannot otherwise not be accessed by the user, such as hidden or system files. Implementation varies among providers. For more information, see about_Providers (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113250). Even when using the Force parameter, the cmdlet cannot override security restrictions.

Of course you have to run this from an elevated powershell console.

After trying my self I hit the same error.
I'd like to suggest another way to do it using WMI :

```
$drive=gwmi win32_logicaldisk -Filter "deviceid='c:'"
$usedspace = $drive.Size -$drive.FreeSpace
```

Comment: thanks for your reply
this is the result

(Get-Childitem -System -File -Recurse -force).count

Get-Childitem : Access to the path 'C:\Documents and Settings' is denied.
At line:1 char:2
+ (Get-Childitem -System -File -Recurse -force).count
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Documents and Settings:String) [Get-ChildItem], UnauthorizedAccess
   Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

And a whole lotta similar error.. Can you try it yourself.. 
thanksAton

Comment: Thanks for the piece code. but I need to find the total no. of files and folders of a particular drive. Can you give me a something like that. It should be able to access all the files in the folders and sub-folders. -force is not working.. I have tried.. 
thanks

Comment: sorry, I'm not aware of another way to do it